# Django: uploaded file is binary. Is it possible to change to utf? So readline() returns unicode rather than bytes

Tags: python, django, unicode

Uploading a file in Django (1.7) using Python 3:

```
f = form.files['file']
f.__repr__()
```

outputs

```
<InMemoryUploadedFile: index.html (text/html)>
```

If I call `f.readline()` I get bytes back.
Normally that would be okay, I could just read the file and decode it, however in this case I'm passing the file on to another function that expects to call `readline()` on the parameter it receives, and `readline()` needs to return unicode rather than bytes.

Is it possible to set encoding or such on an instance of `InMemoryUploadedFile`, so readline would return unicode rather than bytes? Or do I have to use `StringIO` to first read in the entire file and then pass the instance of `StringIO` to my function?

Comment: Django stores the underlying built-in file object under `f.file` - would that help in any way? Perhaps not, as `f.readline` is just a proxy for `f.file.readline`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general way to handle this may be to [write a custom upload handler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/files/uploads/#writing-custom-upload-handlers) and [tell Django to use it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#file-upload-handlers). But I've never done this, so I'm not sure.

But a simple approach would be to just wrap the underlying file object. (If you use [`TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) instead of `StringIO` you shouldn't need to worry about the overhead.)

```
from io import TextIOWrapper

f = form.files['file']
text_f = TextIOWrapper(f.file, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.

Comment: I'd give you a 100 upvotes if I could; this saved me hours of head-scratching.